# Using Array of Pointer in C++

Tags: c, malloc

I coded like that, but it gets seg-fault.

What is wrong?

```
int vector_size = 100000000;

float *rows[vector_size];

for (int i=0; i<vector_size; i++) {
    rows[i] = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*2); // crashed here
    // ...
}
```

Comment: memory overflow for your system perhaps?

Comment: You try to create an array of almost 400MB (on a 32-bit system, double on a 64-bit system)). If you declare the array as a local variable, that's way beyond the stack size of any system (remember that most (all?) compilers store local variables on the stack, and also that the stack is usually in the single-digit MB range).

Comment: Crashed at what value of i? Did you noticed the stack size limit of your system?

Comment: Change `float *rows[vector_size];` to std::vector<float*>, still you will need ~1.2GB of memory. If std::vector will not work then change to std::deque

Comment: assuming 32bit pointers, thats a **381MB** array just for the pointers. Somewhere out there is an automatic storage manager that is weeping profusely. `std::vector<std::array<float,2>> rows(vector_size);`, then sit back and wait for all those value-initializations to finish (it may be awhile).

Comment: With 64 bit pointers it's 720 MB on the stack. That's pretty cool considered the 1 MB default limit for MSVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to allocate a vast amount of memory.  If you really need this many floats, using a separate malloc for each one is probably a bad plan.  Malloc has it's own overheads as there is a minimum block size that can be allocated, and the memory manager also needs to keep track of all those separately allocated areas of memory, not to mention the size of this list of pointers you are holding.

A better solution might be to allocate in a single block enough space for all floats, and the index as an array, rather then try and keep a list of pointers...

So...

```
float *rows = malloc(sizeof(float) * vector_size);
```

might be a better starting point.

Comment: Thank you, I was too stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to allocate memory not in the stack, but in a heap.

```
float **rows = new float*[vector_size];
```

And what message you get about crash?

It don't look like memory overflow, because if memory is ended malloc() returns NULL:\

P.S. sorry for my english)

**upd.** oh, i don't saw comments above